# To hide Suneditor Scrollbar of a text-area

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, suneditor

I have a mail body which is based on sun-editor text-area, and this text-area is in a common div where other elements of mail will be there. Now , there are two scrollbars shown, One is the div and one inside my text-area. I want to hide the scrollbar of sun-editor.
I tried changing in suneditor.js file, but it didn't work and also added style to the editor, but in vain. Please help.
[image: sun-editor text area]
[image: style]